# How do I tell Intellij which module to debug?

Tags: android, debugging, module, intellij-idea

I have an Intellij project open with multiple modules. When I hit ctrl+d it runs and debugs one of my modules. How do I change it so that it runs/debugs a different module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [create the Run/Debug configuration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) and [specify which module to use for the classpath](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-application.html) (**Use Classpath and JDK of the Module**). Then just select it and press Debug button on the main toolbar or you can use a [nice chooser via keyboard shortcut](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/10/invoking-rundebug-actions-in-intellij-idea-9/).

Answer (score 0):

I found it. There is a drop down in the toolbar where you decide which module to run/debug. See in the image where it says "Unnamed"[image]